# Iphone as audio driver

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, iphone, airplay

My macbook pro speakers are totally busted and I think that the soundcard is broken as well because I cannot play music even through headphone jack.  The volume is always grayed out muted and no output device is available in system preferences --> sound including the internal speakers.

Is there anyway I can use my iPhone device as an audio driver as sorts, I can't figure it out with airplay.  I would want to plug in my headphones to my iPhone and then stream whatever audio was coming out of my laptop first to my iPhone and then out the iPhones headphone jack to my ears.  Suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here ya go! Use your iPhone as a wireless audio device for your computer.

http://www.senstic.com/iphone/pocketaudio/pocketaudio.aspx

Comment: Yes - this is exactly what I need - thank you!